# Retrieve a file from an FTP Directory

Tags: c#, ftp, .net-4.5

I have an application and I wish to download one file each day from an FTP directory. I want to download the file from the FTP site but not remove it, so that other users can also download it.

if my ftp site address is ftp://ftp.mySite.com/ how do I go about this? Browsing the internet I so far have this. I have not yet ran the code as I do want to make sure I do not remove the file from the site only download a copy. Also it is possible the file may not be there what is the best way to check if the file is there?

```
 FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(host + "/" + remoteFile);
 ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
 ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
 ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
 ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;            
 ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
```

Comment: 1. When you download, you in fact copy the file, so it stays there. 2. Use List command to list available files.

Comment: @should I use list command even if I know the file name I want?

Comment: You wouldn't need to use it if you indeed know the file name. It is safe to try and run this code.

Comment: One thing I've just realised. Where do I specify where I would like the file downloaded to?